# Rooted phone but cannot change hosts file

Tags: root-access, hosts, samsung-galaxy-s8+

I rooted on my S8+. I used the app root checker to check that it's rooted.
I was attempting to block ads by hosts files with this [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/)

I attempted to copy the hosts file to my pc, changed it, and pushed it back... got:

```
adb: error: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
hosts: 0 files pushed. 62.2 MB/s (456580 bytes in 0.007s)
```

I then attempted to do it by following this [tutorial](https://www.modmy.com/how-modify-hosts-file-your-android-device) which uses apps to change the files

I did change the host file permissions to -rw-rw-rw-

Then I tried to use the editor to add some DNS but I was unable to save the hosts files once again. When I tried to save it, I got a Toast saying root permissions were given to the text editor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mount `/system` read/write? Did you disable `dm-verity` with/after rooting?

Comment: Quick question: did you try AdAway?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman why to put extra burden of app when Android's resolver is already doing that for you. My opinion.

Comment: AdAway can overlay (bind mount) /system/etc/hosts no need to modify system

Comment: @alecxs valid point. But all that needed is `mount -o bind /data/media/0/.hosts /etc/hosts` or something similar.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I guess that, if one wants to do this manually, then they must find a way to run their command at startup. If their kernel doesn't support init.d out of the box, the hacks are either dirty or require init.d emulators, aka apps. Bottom line: if the kernel doesn't already support init.d, then AdAway appears to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman injecting `init.d` requires putting 2 lines in any `.rc` file. But yeah, it depends on what a user wants. Internet traffic may leak on startup by the time apps are loaded. It's another problem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Putting two lines in any `.rc` file **plus** repacking and flashing `boot.img`. If memory serves, the `/` directory, aka rootfs, is populated anew at every boot, with the contents of `boot.img`.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally was able to come back to this issue.
I was unable to mount the adb with write permissions either because i was not su or it would deny me to change the host files...

I tried to write the text on the hosts file but it was a file with hundreds of lines... even seemed that android was not able to store it in the "copy/paste"

So in the end I used Solid explorer 2 from play store.

I wrote a hosts file... then i navigate to the /system/etc/ 
and I rename hosts to "hosts.old" and my "hosts.txt" to "hosts"

until now it seems to be working fine

I'm not considering this an answer because I was unable to write on hosts and someone can come up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

i try to find some solution about this. but i found it my self.
i go to recovery mode.at twrp you go setting. and (i forgot) try to find something that will give you checkbox list. and tick check box that called 'system'. niw i can easily replace my hosts file

edit: sorry not setting.go to mount and tick system box